# A short story about a tribe that believes that a dragon swallows the sun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about anthropologists studying a tribe. When the tribe is educated about the solar eclipse and how it works, the sun does not reappear because they did not beat their drums. Title? Author? Possibly Bradbury.

Comment: Please add as much detail as possible to help to identify the story: character names, locations, plot details, etc.

Comment: Sorry, Tim- that's really all there is to the story as I remember it. The tribe has a ritual of beating drums to keep the dragon from swallowing the sun. When they fail to perform the ritual, having been enlightened by the scientists on how a solar eclipse works, we are left waiting while the minutes pass and the sun does not reappear.